# match url with title in table doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I'am trying to match a title from an URL with a title from a `mysql` row.
but a cant get it to work.

this is my link:

```
http://www.domain.com/article/What-the-HECK
```

this is my `-HTacces` file line:

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ article.php?id=$1
```

this is my select from table:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$title = str_replace('-', ' ', $id);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE status = '1' AND title = '$title' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());
```

The title in `mysql` is "What-the-heck" and the output on the page if i'm trying to echo it out is exaclty the same as the mysql title

Comment: i can't get the article WHERE title = $title??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Disable `MultiViews` since your PHP filename is same as path name
2. Lowercase your `$title` before comparing.

**.htaccess:**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^article/(.+)$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Inside PHP code use `lower` function in MySQL query around `title` column comparison.

**btw You must use `PDO_MySQL` or `MySQLi` otherwise this code is prone to SQL injection attack.**

Comment: okey sorry now its getting to complicated for me. what if i would ad the id and the title in the URL and the rewrite it in the htaccess file so the URL would look like this http://www.domain.com/article.php?id=3&title=What-the-HECK == http://www.domain.com/3/What-the-HECK

Answer (score 0):

it worked with the id in the URL

http://www.domain.com/article-3-What-the-HECK

RewriteRule ^article-([0-9]+)-(.*)$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2

http://www-domain.com/article-3-What-the-HECK

now its working and i still have the title in the URL

hope it will give some more keywords for my SEO performance..